# Print an n level reverse pyramid as follows where n is a positive integer taken as input

Tags: python

Print an n level reverse pyramid as follows where n is a positive integer taken as input.

```
Each triangle will be made out of “*” symbols and the spaces will be filled by "#" symbols for each row. For example, a 3 level reverse pyramid will look as follows:

    *****
    #***#
    ##*##
    Note: There should be no space between the stars. Remember to not print any extra character or spaces or else your solution could be rejected.
    Sample input:
    4
    Sample output:
    *******
    #*****#
    ##***##
    ###*###
```

Below is the code:

Code:

```
def print_pattern(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        for j in range(i-1):
            print('#',end='')
        for k in range((n+1)-i):
            print('*',end= '')
        for m in range(n-i):
            print('*',end='')
        for j in range(i-1):
            print('#',end='')
        print('\r')
print_pattern(4)
```

Error:

```
None of my Test cases are Passing
```

Comment: It seems fishy that you are printing `\r` rather than `\n`, which is much more common and the tests might expect. Also, rather than writing for-loops to print one character at a time, you can create strings in Python by assembling their parts: for example, `s1 = '#' * (i - 1)`. Do something similar for `s2`. Then just print them: `print(s1 + s2 + s1)`

Comment: I did try \n and the results are still failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys i got the solution

```
n=input()
i=n-1
while i>-1:
        print('#'*(n-i-1) + '*'*(2*i+1)+'#'*(n-i-1))
        i=i-1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_pattern(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
      for s in range(1,i):
        print('#',end=" ")
      for p in range(1,((n*n)+1)-((n*n)//2)-i-i):
        print("*",end=" ")
      for s in range(1,i):
        print('#',end=" ") 
      print('\r')
print_pattern(4)
```

you can try this and change the value of `n` as per your requirement

Comment: Input
4
Solution output
* * * * * * 
# * * * * # 
# # * * # # 
# # # # # # 
Expected output
*******
#*****#
##***##
###*###

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate how much length of `*` and `#` occupies in each line before printing and just use `str` repeat operator `*` to repeat those symbols

Each line's length is fixed at `L = 2*n - 1` i.e. the total length of `*`s and `#`s will be `L` at each level.

At each level `n` decreases by 1 and the number of `*`s can be calculated by `2*n-1` at that level.

Now you can guess how much length of `#`s should occupy on each side. It is `(L-l)/2`.

Then having these in hand, you can easily print strings using repeat operator.

Code is :

```
def print_pattern(n):
  L = 2*n-1
  while (n > 0):
    l = 2*n-1
    h = int((L-l)/2)
    print('#'*h+'*'*l+'#'*h)
    n = n - 1
```